# Access date query using dd/mm/yyyy returns zero found

Tags: date, ms-access

My Access database displays dates in `DD/MM/YYYY` format. One row contains date as `07/06/2014`, but my query says "not found".

Here is my select query:

```
strSql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE MyDate = #" & Me.fldFindWhat.Value & "#"
```

`MsgBox strSql` displays

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE MyDate = #07/06/2014#
```

Where is the problem then?

Comment: localization? MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY maybe?

Comment: @Dil Dilshan - mysql tag should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with Access date queries for people who use the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. The problem is that the Access Database Engine does not pay any attention to the Regional Settings in Windows itself; it **always** interprets *ambiguous* `#xx/yy/zzzz#` date literals as `mm/dd/yyyy`. Adding to the confusion is the fact that it will interpret *unambiguous* `#xx/yy/zzzz#` date literals as `dd/mm/yyyy` if `xx` is greater than 12.

So, the Access Database Engine will interpret `#13/06/2014#` as `June 13, 2014`. The date literal is unambiguous since there is no 13th month.

However, the Access Database Engine will **always** interpret `#07/06/2014#` as `July 6, 2014`. This is true regardless of the Regional Settings in the Windows Control Panel.

To avoid this problem, always use the unambiguous `yyyy/mm/dd` format in date literals, e.g.,

```vbs
strSql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE MyDate = #" & _
        Format(Me.fldFindWhat.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

You could also use the `mm/dd/yyyy` format in date literals, e.g.,

```vbs
strSql = "SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE MyDate = #" & _
        Format(Me.fldFindWhat.Value, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
```

... but people who are used to seeing `dd/mm/yyyy` dates could find this confusing when analyzing debug output.

Comment: "yyyy/mm/dd" is not absolutely unambiguous to Format as "/" is not a slash but the localized date separator, which can be "/", "-", ".", even a space. Thus, do escape the slash to obtain a literal slash: "yyyy\/mm\/dd".